# How to make fsolve function work inside a for loop?

Tags: python, solver, nonlinear-optimization

I am writing a function to calculate three nonlinear equations. I have the function to calculate them, but the thing is I give initial guess to them - which works fine. But now I have a constraint for x between (1/4 and 1/3). For that, I am making 2 for lops. One is for ptinting 13 different values, the other one for the constraint.

However the code does not give me the result at all:

```
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
def equations(vars):

    x, y, z = vars
    eq1 = ((x / (1 - x)) - (((2.5*np.cos(z)) / (8 * np.pi * np.sin(z) ** 2)) * (1 + (design_ratio * np.tan(z)))))
    eq2 = ((y / (1 + y)) - (2.5 / (8 * np.pi * np.cos(z))) * (1 -design_ratio *( (1 / np.tan(z)))))
    eq3 = np.tan(z) - ((1-x) /( 1.40 * (1+y)))
    return [eq1, eq2, eq3]
n=13
for i in range(0, n):
    for j in range(25555, 33333):
    x = 0.00001 *x
x, y, z =  fsolve(equations, (0.328, 0.048, 28))
print(x, y, z)
```

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, using a loop is a terrible approach to handle the box constraint  `1/4 <= x <= 1/3`. Since `fsolve` doesn't support (box) constraints, you can rewrite the problem

```
Solve F(x,y,z) = 0 with 1/4 <= x <= 1/3
```

as an equivalent minimization problem

```
min np.sum(F(x,y,z)**2) s.t. 1/4 <= x <= 1/3
```

and solve it by means of [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) like this:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def F(vars):
    x, y, z = vars
    eq1 = ((x / (1 - x)) - (((2.5*np.cos(z)) / (8 * np.pi * np.sin(z) ** 2)) * (1 + (design_ratio * np.tan(z)))))
    eq2 = ((y / (1 + y)) - (2.5 / (8 * np.pi * np.cos(z))) * (1 -design_ratio *( (1 / np.tan(z)))))
    eq3 = np.tan(z) - ((1-x) /( 1.40 * (1+y)))
    return np.array([eq1, eq2, eq3])

bounds = [(1./4, 1./3), (None, None), (None, None)]

res = minimize(lambda vars: np.sum(F(vars)**2), x0=(0.328, 0.048, 28), bounds=bounds)
```

Comment: It makes sense now.. But I do not understand why I am getting a still bigger values than my limit:    0.20
1     0.30
2     0.38
3     0.42
4     0.49
5     0.58
6     0.66
7     0.72
8     0.81
9     0.87
10    0.92
11    0.94
12    0.98
13    1.00